# How can I look up data in one dataframe based on a calculated value in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two input files:

1. Insider trades in public companies for the last 10 years
2. Daily historical prices and returns of all stocks for the last 10 years

I want to output: For each insider trade in the insiders file, I want to get the stock price for each of the last 30 days before the trade and each of the next 30 days after the trade.

I am using pandas in python to do this analysis

I have cleaned and filtered my data to keep only the columns that I need such that the two dataframes look like this:

**Insider Trades**

|  | tdate | stockTicker | Buy/Sell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-08-03 | A | Buy |
| 2 | 2010-08-03 | A | Buy |
| 3 | 2010-08-03 | B | Sell |
| 4 | 2010-08-05 | A | Sell |
| 5 | 2010-08-05 | B | Buy |

**Prices**

|  | Date | ticker | Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-08-03 | A | -0.3 |
| 2 | 2010-08-05 | A | 0.1 |
| 3 | 2010-08-03 | B | -0.8 |
| 4 | 2010-08-05 | B | 0.2 |

Since I want the stock price for each of the last 30 days and next 30 days, I add columns with labels -30, -29 , ... , 0 ... 1, 2, ... , 30 to Insider Trades:

|  | tdate | stockTicker | Buy/Sell | -30 | -29 | ... | 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-08-03 | A | Buy |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2010-08-03 | A | Buy |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2010-08-03 | B | Sell |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 2010-08-05 | A | Sell |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 2010-08-05 | B | Buy |  |  |  |  |

How do I now look up the values for Insider Trade's columns -30...30 in the Prices DF  by checking for (tdate - columnName) AND stockTicker to get the 'Return' value from Prices, for all rows? I would like to display NaN when the stock + date combination does not exist in prices.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
insider_df['tdate'] = pd.to_datetime(insider_df['tdate'])
prices_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(prices_df['Date'])

prices_df = prices_df.sort_values(by='Date')
prices_df = prices_df.set_index('Date')

days = 30
ofs = pd.Timedelta(days=days)

def fn(row):
    tmp = prices_df[row['tdate'] - ofs:row['tdate'] + ofs]
    tmp = tmp[tmp['ticker'] == row['stockTicker']]
    tmp = dict(zip((tmp.index - row['tdate']).days, tmp['Return']))

    return {**row, **{d: tmp.get(d, np.nan) for d in range(-days, days+1)}}

x = pd.DataFrame(insider_df.apply(fn, axis=1).to_list())
print(x.fillna("").to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | tdate | stockTicker | Buy/Sell | -30 | -29 | -28 | -27 | -26 | -25 | -24 | -23 | -22 | -21 | -20 | -19 | -18 | -17 | -16 | -15 | -14 | -13 | -12 | -11 | -10 | -9 | -8 | -7 | -6 | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2010-08-03 00:00:00 | A | Buy |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | -0.3 |  | 0.1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2010-08-03 00:00:00 | A | Buy |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | -0.3 |  | 0.1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2010-08-03 00:00:00 | B | Sell |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | -0.8 |  | 0.2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2010-08-05 00:00:00 | A | Sell |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | -0.3 |  | 0.1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 2010-08-05 00:00:00 | B | Buy |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | -0.8 |  | 0.2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |